# Foreign key constraint makes SELECT query return 0 rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've been given this database structure:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `account` (
  `accountType` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`accountType`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `username`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `username` (
  `usernameID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `password` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `phoneNr` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `accountType` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`usernameID`),
  KEY `accountType` (`accountType`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `username`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `username_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`accountType`) REFERENCES `account` (`accountType`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

Now, I want to SELECT a user from the username table. In MySQL workbench I get the results I'm looking for with:

```
SELECT name FROM username;
```

However, when using a mysqli query in PHP i get num_rows => 0 in my result object, like this:

[image]
(The var_dump above the result object is the query I'm sending in)

It works if I remove the KEY from the username table, so I assume that's where the problem lies. How should I alter my SELECT query?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `name` is a reserved word in MySQL. You may just need to escape it using the backtick character like so,

```
SELECT `name` FROM username;
```

See [Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. Not even SELECT * FROM username; works.

Comment: And the username table has data?

Comment: Definitely. If I remove the KEY 'account'-line from the username table the query works.

Comment: Actually, no, it doesn't work with even with everything stripped away besides the username table (without the foreign key). God damn it. Must be something wrong with the database then?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it seems like InnoDB was the issue. As soon as I removed ENGINE=InnoDB from the username table, everything worked.